# how to call .lib functions that i created in c++ in nasm

Tags: assembly, nasm

i have .lib file that i created in c++ with several functions.

```
_declspec(dllexport) int atoi_new(char * c , int len){

    int ar = 0;
    int f = 0;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++){

            f *= 10;
            ar  = (int) c[i];
            ar -= 0x30;
            f += ar ;
            }
        return f;
    };
```

this maybe not a good example but you get the idea .
know i want to use this function from .lib file in nasm any idea how to do this ?

Comment: Declare it as `extern` in your assembly file and link against the library?

Comment: how to import library into nasm when i use this "import libs.lib" i got this "libs.asm:4: error: parser: instruction expected"

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the functions as C, otherwise the names get mangled and you would have to look it up, what name the compiler made up.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

_declspec(dllexport) int atoi_new(char * c , int len);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

or

```
extern "C"  _declspec(dllexport) int atoi_new(char * c , int len);
```

Comment: now how to use it in nasm dump is...@Symbol Symbol Offset Type Applied To Index Name -------- ---------------- ----------------- -------- ------ 0000000C DIR32NB 00000000 E _atoi_new 00000058 SECREL 00000000 E _atoi_new 0000005C SECTION 0000 E _atoi_new 00000094 SECREL 00000000 E _atoi_new 00000098 SECTION 0000 E _atoi_new'